# JQuery Hover not Working in SharePoint 2013 Calendar list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, jquery

I used following URL for loading all resources item in SharePoint 2013 Calendar List and Its working fine as per my expectation.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2013/04/10/sharepoint-group-calendar-adding-default-users.aspx

Now I implemented jQuery Hover functionality for item Preview. The Hover working fine for Currently Logged user which is in top row in the List. But the same hover not working for remaining resources.

The following simple jQuery I used in the SharePoint 2013 Calendar list.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('a[href*="DispForm.aspx"]').hover(function(){alert('Mouse Hover');});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this issue is happening because you can using timeout for manipulating the DOM Elements.

Try below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href*="DispForm.aspx"]').on("hover",function(){
        alert('Mouse Hover');
    });
});
```